# Using pronoun after similarly conjugated verb?

Tags: pronombres, conjugación

### Español

Me encontré esta frase que me confundió en una canción : "hoy me muero yo".
¿Cuál es el significado de añadir el pronombre después de haber conjugado el verbo?

---

### Inglés

I came across a phrase in a song which confused me. "Hoy me muero yo".

What is the meaning of adding the pronoun after you've conjugated the verb?

---

> Pinta, pinta
>
> Pinta su carita
>
> Sin esa carita
>
> Hoy me muero yo
>
> Pequeña, echate pa'aquá

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! We hope to see your contributions regularly :)

Comment: If you know Spanish, we encourage you to write your questions in Spanish. If you are learning it, don't worry about possible mistakes, we'll help you.

Comment: It's just to add some emphasis. Same in English when you say "I do like it"

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You can read our [FAQ] to know how this site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Español**

Es muy común usar este orden (adverbio-verbo-sujeto) en frases cortas cuando se quiere dar más importancia a "cuándo" se lleva a cabo la acción en vez de la acción en sí misma, y el verbo es intransitivo. En estos ejemplos, se incluyen posibles preguntas.

---

**Inglés**

It's very common to use this order (adverb-verb-subject) in short sentences when you want to stress "when" the action is taken rather than the action itself, and the verb is intransitive. In these examples, I include possible questions.

> — ¿Quién se muere hoy? o ¿qué pasa hoy?
>     — Hoy me muero yo.
>
> — ¿Quién cocinó ayer? o ¿qué pasó ayer?
>     — Ayer cocinó Raquel.
>
> — ¿Quién hablará mañana?, ¿hay algún acto mañana? o ¿cuándo hablará el presidente?
>     — Mañana hablará el presidente.
>
> — ¿Vienes al cine?
>    — No puedo, luego vendrán mis amigos.

Answer (score 4):

Without a little bit of more context it is hard to know the exact reason why this phrase was written like this.

When you do this kind of things is to provide more emphasis to what you are saying.

For example, let's pretend that two people are talking about something that has put them in a bad situation and one of them say:

> Me quiero morir.

Meaning that things are so bad that she would like to die, figuratively speaking of course.

As a reply the other one says:

> No, hoy me muero yo.

Meaning that this person feels much more embarrassed so today it will be HER turn to die or that she should die first, again figuratively speaking.

So, in a nutshell, this is not a way that everyday speech is used, only in very specific cases where you want to provide some emphasis to the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Es cuestión de énfasis.  El "yo" al final es más enfático que antes del verbo.

Pero en una canción, también puede ser cuestión de sincronizar la letra con la música.